# CK Editor, placeholder plugin & dynamic items

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

For my needs, I need different set of placeholder items for different CKEditor instances.  I have changed the dialogs\placeholder.js to select box.  I am trying to add placeholder items via few different ways, but I am having no luck.  My dream would be to add the the placeholders via the on page CKEditor call - CKEDITOR.replace ...

```
**dialogs\placeholder.js**

elements: [
// Dialog window UI elements.
{
id: 'name',
type: 'select',
style: 'width: 100%;',
label: lang.name,
items:[
    ['CompanyName'],
    ['Address'],
    ['City'],
    ['State'],
    ['Zip']
],
```

Thanks in advance.

http://ckeditor.com/addon/placeholder

Comment: Sorry, your question is unclear. What exactly you want to do? "add the the placeholders via the on page CKEditor call - CKEDITOR.replace". Do you want to have a different set of items per editor?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear.  Yes, I have a different set of items for each editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out. Edit the dialog page *and write bad (improper) code*

This is what worked for me.  (ColdFusion)

Change where the dialog points to (in my case from .JS to .CFM):

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.add( 'placeholder', this.path + 'dialogs/placeholder.CFM' );
```

Open the /placeholder/dialogs/placeholder.js and save as placeholder.cfm

On the top of cfm page:

```
<cfquery datasource="data" name="query">
SELECT DISTINCT State FROM Addresses ORDER BY State</cfquery>
```

In the middle:

```
items:[
<cfoutput query="query">
        ['#State#'],
</cfoutput>
],
```

**Do not add script tags or such, don't add anything else.**  That's it.